# Trimming hashed password (for user identification)

Tags: php, sql, hash

http://www.vidyasocks.com/forums.php?id=1&id=1

as you can see at the bottom I am using hash as a way to identify users. How can I trim off the rest after 10 characters?

Comment: Fyi, about that (annoying) ticker on your website: It's `You're too slow`, not `Your to slow`. Please do not rape the english language like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trimming runs the risks of hash collisions where two users potentially share the same trimmed portion.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science)

Hashing algorithms go to great length to avoid this possibility so modification of the hashed results in any way is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr):

```
echo substr($str, 0, 10);
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> $hash = md5('whatever');
>>> echo $hash;
008c5926ca861023c1d2a36653fd88e2
>>> echo substr($hash, 0, 10);
008c5926ca
```

In case you want to do it in the database when SELECTing the hash, you can use the [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function of MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT LEFT('008c5926ca861023c1d2a36653fd88e2', 10);
+----------------------------------------------+
| LEFT('008c5926ca861023c1d2a36653fd88e2', 10) |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 008c5926ca                                   |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I keep getting Fatal error: Function name must be a string in D:\Hosting\8763814\html\post2.php on line 23 –

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr):

```
$hash = substr($hash,0,10);
```

Comment: What would it would like for sha1?

Comment: @GarrettRobertson, I am sorry, I dont understand.

Comment: I never used $hash before. I just have $title=  sha1($_POST['title']);

Comment: How would I use $hash instead of sha1?

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in D:\Hosting\8763814\html\post2.php on line 23

Comment: @GarrettRobertson, There was a small typo. Please check again.